# How to get checkout/cart_sidebar block in Magento from everywhere

Tags: magento, checkout

Let me know how can I get "checkout/cart_sidebar" block as HTML into variable ?
I need to get it from my own magento controller

As I see "checkout/cart_sidebar"  depends on "Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar" class

so may It is possible to get this template via some Mage:: Static Instance Methods

I tried a few ways I couldnt (

thanks

Comment: could you show me example ?

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: Dear Meenakshi ! I need to assign my 
"checkout/cart_sidebar" template into variable from php script. I need to send it to my browser/javascript for further action )

Comment: Is There any Magento Experts who knows how to get it except someone who like decreasing rate only )) lol

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you could try something like this:

```
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar');

    $block->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml');
```

Depending on your configuration (Config -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart Sidebar), you can render the template with

```
    $block->toHtml();
```

If you use a custom template, you could ignore the config value so it renders anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Actions in layout xml configs are just a block method call.

The two below are equivlent

```
<block type     = "checkout/cart_sidebar" 
       name     = "cart_sidebar" 
       as       = "cartExplorer" 
       template = "checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" 
       before   = "-">
<action method="addItemRender">
    <type>configurable</type>
    <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block>
    <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
</action>


<!-- Programatically create the block -->
<?php 
    $this->getLayout()
         ->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar', 'cart_sidebar')
         ->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml');
         ->addItemRender(
             'configurable', 
             'checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable',
             'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml'
         )

?>


<!-- This is if it was already created in a layout.xml file -->
<?php 

$this->getLayout()
     ->getBlock('cart_sidebar')
     ->addItemRender(
         'configurable', 
         'checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable',
         'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml'
     )

?>
```

Hope this helps!